# ExpressJs: Config variables in different environments

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can't I define a variable to be used in different envs when I define the env?

```
app.configure 'development', () ->
 app.use express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true})
 mongoose.connect 'mongodb://xxx:xxx-db2011@sun.memberd.mongohq.com:10012/xxxx'
 test = "ola23"

app.configure 'production', () ->
 app.use express.errorHandler()
 mongoose.connect 'mongodb://xxx:xxx-db2011@sun.memberd.mongohq.com:10012/xxxx'
 test = "ola"
```

I can define the "`mongoose.connect`", why can't I define `test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code sets a local variable to that configuration function to a value.  I'm sure that works.  But how do you need to use that `test` variable?

The way you've done it here, it simply will go away as soon as this function finishes, you aren't sending or saving it anywhere.  The `mongoose.connect` line, does something, it passes in a string to a function that uses that string to do something awesome.  `test = "ola"` only sets a local variable.

So without knowing how you want to use `test` it's hard to advise more.  But you probably want this instead:

```
app.set 'test', 'ola'
```

Which you can then retrive `"ola"` later with:

```
app.get 'test'
```

Comment: fix the retrieve of the 'test' using `app.get 'test'` not `app.set 'test'`